# How to or tools for inserting and cleaning data after in automated test across multiple environments

Tags: automated-tests

I want to execute automated tests across different environments, each one has their own database and data it's not replicated across all database, so we have different data on DEV, QA, and PRO databases, meaning automated test could fail due to different data. It mainly microservices against a DB.

Is there any techniques or tools that do something like inserting a data set for testing, run tests, and then rollback to original state on the database??

Comment: Using `@BeforeMethod`, `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterMethod`,  `@AfterTest` methods are for executing some code before and after a method or test, depending how you declare them

Comment: Thanks, so this means I should script what actions need to be perform in the database. Any ideas of tools for automating this process?? I was also thinking on using a in memory db like H2, apply the db schema from prooduction db, and then add base data, perform tests, and then simple drop the in memory db.